# Rejected lambda expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The following lambda expression seems to get rejected by Clang as well as MSVC, while GCC accepts it. Is the expression legal according to C++20 standard?

```
static_assert([]<int I>() -> decltype([]<int = {I + I}>{ return true; })
    { return {}; }.template operator()<{}>()());
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/zxzxqdofo)

---

The error message from Clang:

```
<source>:14:48: error: expected expression
   14 | static_assert([]<int I>() -> decltype([]<int = {I + I}>{ return true; })
      |                                                ^
<source>:15:40: error: expected expression
   15 |     { return {}; }.template operator()<{}>()());
      |
```

The error message from MSVC:

```
<source>(14): error C2065: 'I': undeclared identifier
<source>(15): error C3889: call to object of class type '<lambda_1>': no matching
call operator found
<source>(14): note: could be 'auto <lambda_1>::operator ()(void) const'
<source>(15): note: 'auto <lambda_1>::operator ()(void) const': could not deduce
template argument for '_T1'
```

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2049.html? Addressed in https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2450.html resolution

Comment: ^ That would be why Clang rejects it. But MSVC looks outright buggy here, `I` should be visible at that point.

Comment: It seems indeed that Clang rejects this for a different reason. Interestingly enough though, Clang's trunk build still rejects: `static_assert([]<int I>() -> decltype([]<int = int{I + I}>{ return true; }){ return {}; }.template operator()<int{}>()());` If someone can post the related wording why `I` should be visible here, I'll report this bug to Microsoft.

Comment: I wouldn't even look for the wording, to me it's obvious that `I` should be visible there. Regarding Clang: interestingly, Clang 17 accepts it. And trunk starts accepting if I add `constexpr` to the lambda. I'd report it too, looks like a bug.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm also getting an internal compiler error from GCC when starting to add type-constraints in the mix: `internal compiler error: tree check: accessed elt 1 of 'tree_vec' with -1 elts in add_to_template_args`

Comment: Clang rejects this because it doesn’t implement the [(putative) resolution](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2023/p2308r0.html) to [CWG2049](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2049.html).